# How to review seemingly well thought out first posts?

Tags: discussion, voting, review

So I've encountered a few posts for review specifically under first posts. These posts seem to be OK at a glance. They have no glaring format issues, no need for comment, and they fit the Stack Overflow guidelines.

The problem is that I can't necessarily tell if they are correct. I guess they should be skipped in this case perhaps. Is there a way to say that something has been "reviewed for standards compliance" without voting something up? Is there a protocol to follow, like "always make a comment on a first post regardless if it is a good or bad"?

Comment: Kudos for being willing to click that "Skip" button, and trying to do the best thing in the first place.

Comment: So... I've never reviewed "First Posts" before and just checked it because of this question, and I am shocked to discover there isn't a "Looks good" button! The only way to say you're done reviewing is to vote up or down, edit, comment, or flag. Downvoting, flagging, and sometimes editing are often not a good way to greet a new user, making useless comments or trivial edits is a bad idea, and often I don't think the questions are worthy of an upvote.... sure I could Skip but doesn't the question stay in the queue in that case?? This doesn't seem like a good system for evaluating first posts

Comment: @Rachel it stays in the queue until someone else reviews it.  Skipping allows others to review it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't strictly an answer, but I've come across much the same issue being here for about a month (after using SO for a few years). So I'm probably a good use-case.

I find it rather addictive to review other posts, but where I don't know if the post is applicable/accurate with regard to a particular subject I'll always skip it rather than upvote by default - that's just too easy and some just don't make the effort.

If anything, and where applicable, I'm more likely to correct grammar or fix layout/markdown failures, improve readability and hit <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> as my way of contributing.

What I do know is that posts are often well thought out, well structured and provide what I consider good effort - but, much like you, I can't accept/upvote them from a compliance perspective - I don't think it's a good idea to do so! From a personal perspective it's better to just skip and leave for those better experienced in a particular field - which I find myself doing on a regular basis.

I don't think a compliance-tick would be constructive, despite it's draw. Sure there could be a "looks good" button, but then domain experts could think it's utter rubbish.

Despite all my skips to date, I've never seen the first post queue beyond 20-30.

Comment: `I find it rather addictive to review other posts` -- SE's nefarious plan is working, muahahaha.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Nefarious indeed!

Answer (score 2):

There have been many requests for a <kbd>Looks Good!</kbd> button in the first posts or late answers review queue here...

You are right in my opinion to <kbd>Skip</kbd> the review when you think that the post looks good, but you cannot tell if it's a correct answer or a valid question. Other reviewers more experienced on the topic in question might have a better idea about the quality of that post.

However I think there's another major drawback of a <kbd>Looks Good!</kbd> button: By clicking this button you would increase your review count for that queue (and thus work towards certain badges) without providing any useful feedback to the post owner. The only thing this review action then would do, is kicking this post out of the review queue and thus prevent other (in this case probably more experienced) users from reviewing it.
The <kbd>Skip</kbd>-button only kicks this post out of *your* review queue - so you don't need to worry about that post anymore ;)